# CodeIgniter HMVC: extend a library or create a global controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I've started using HMVC in Codeigniter with Modular Extension and i want to create a set of methods avalaible in the whole application.

For example i've this three methods:

- a method to retrieve te app name
- a method for getting the right view folder depending on the user agent
- a method to load assets

What's the best way to do this:

1. I'm using a model inside a module which is then requested from all other modules
2. I may extend or create a library/helper

now i'm using the first solution but I have come to doubt that it can slow down the application.

Comment: if its really only those 3 methods couldnt you just have that as a stand alone model and autoload it?

Comment: yes i'm doing so but then i may have to use also a controller and i don't want to change all later

Comment: ya, both approaches are valid.  Wouldn't you just be using/loading the model to do all those things from the 'front' controller and then calling another controller from there anyway?  It seems like your model approach would be fine then.

Comment: Personally I would create this as a helper and then autoload the helper. I'm not sure of your system, but by requesting that module in every other module, you're giving the requesting module access to everything in the module containing your "global" functions. (Just saying that is confusing). If you're okay with that then go for it. But as I stated above, I'd seperate these out into a helper that was autoloaded.

Comment: @matt also in a helper i would have access to all its methods from the requestin controller, right? anyway i may also autoload the model

Comment: @Matteo, yes you'd have access through the CI object.. one of the benefits of using HMVC is that you don't have to create your own CI instance and can use variables defined by the main instance created in your other modules.

Answer (score 0):

I would put this one in a base controller. Like this one: https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-controller